# Screen gets distorted when scrolling in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scrolling

[image: Distorted image of the screen]

My screen becomes like this when I scroll with my mouse in Windows 7,

Comment: Can you give us more information? Has that always been an issue? If not, when did it start? Do you remember changing anything before? Does that only happen in Internet Explorer, or other browsers, or in any place where you scroll? Please [edit] your question and add more details, and please don't **make them bold**, and capitalize properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your CPU is running slowly, maybe not fast enough for windows 7 or it could be that you have so many programs running that your RAM is being blocked up so your screen can't get a fast enough refresh rate